# 16.04 System error on startup

Tags: 16.04

I'm using an old PC with Ubuntu 16.04. I've been using this computer for a few years and Ubuntu has been running fine. Recently I upgraded to 16.04 and now every time I start up the computer, I get two or three pop-up messages saying "System Error" on the desktop right after I log in.

How can I fix this issue without reinstalling? I don't want to reinstall because I have two users on this computer with profiles that I want to keep.

Comment: What are the errors? Click "report error" and list the errors here.

Comment: The error message says, atop has crashed.

Comment: The message saying atop crashed is probably caused by bug #1022865 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atop/+bug/1022865). If you don't use atop, just uninstall it.